# Connecting to a remote database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make siteA.com to connect to the database of siteB.com.However i am getting connection timed out.I already added siteA.com as a "Remote Database Access Hosts" in cpanel used by siteB.com but still no luck.

SiteA and siteB are on 2 different hosts and in case i put both on the same host , they work just fine.

P.S i am using php PDO to setup the connection

Here is my mysql connection setting for siteA

```
<?php
$hostname = "ipaddressofSiteB"; 
$db_name = "mybigdb";
$db_user = "harry";
$db_pass = "fcr2^WK&M";
?>
```

Comment: The host might be firewalled. Check if the port is opened.

Comment: u allowed external connections to siteA from siteB and does the above IP has the port part as well? usually 3306 ie: ipaddressofSiteB::3306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My webhost had blocked remote mysql connection

Had to contact them with ip of SiteB and port (3306) for them to unblock outgoing connections

Answer (score 0):

Try to check:

- **Firewall**. Make sure the siteB.com is configured to accept incoming connections to port 3306.
- **MySQL configuration**. Specially `bind-address` in MySQL configuration on siteB.com (located in `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in most cases), because if `bind-address` is set to `127.0.0.1` only local connections will be accepted.

BTW, you can do faster/simpler connection testing through `telnet`:

```
user@pc:~$ telnet siteB.com 3306
```